# Having problems with the screen resolution and screen size when Build & Running my project in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I build and run my game the graphics are very low quality. I decided to combat this by increasing my resolution, but for some reason all that did was make my application window larger upon building and running it rather than having better image quality. I am not sure where my mistake/ misunderstanding lies and would appreciate any help, as all I want to achieve is a reasonably sized window with the same graphics one gets when Maximizing on play before running one's project in unity.

I changed this by in a start method of a script writing;

```
Screen.SetResolution (1920, 1080, false);
```

I am not sure if I would also be able to do this in player settings as one is only able to change the window screen and height to the best of my knowledge...

NOTE:
I am building this for mac

HighQuality[Editor]

[image]

LowQuality[Build]

[image]

P.S. please do not vote this question down. I have only asked one question prior to this one and it originally was at 1- which got me banned for 1 day. I am therefore very unexperienced in stack overflow so if you have anything to object against my question please just leave it in the comments and I will be happy to edit my post.

Comment: Saying "please don't vote this down" won't prevent people from doing so. They will if your question does not follow SO guidelines.

Comment: well i just just asking the because i am new and would happily edit my question rather than being completely banned after asking two questions...

Comment: I can understand where you are coming from though @Programmer

Comment: Add a concrete code example

Comment: "I decided to combat this by increasing my resolution" Please show how you did this. A screenshot of where you changed the resolution would be good. Also, please show the high quality and then what you consider to be the lower quality. Also, what Platform are you building to?

Comment: I am building for mac

Comment: Ok. What is bad quality after building? The UI, Material Textures or Sprites? If you don't mind, a screenshot of the normal/editor and low/build image would be good.

Comment: I am not 100 percent sure what exactly, but just take a look for yourself....

Comment: @Programmer has this question been given up on?

Comment: Nope. I am typing an answer.

Comment: Oh, ok thanks a lot @Programmer

Comment: @Programmer I'm not sure if this helps but when I change my graphics from 'fastest' to 'fantastic' in Project settings there is no difference. This gives me the impression that the build quality is so low because the graphics are stuck on 'fastest' setting...

Comment: Are your lights real-time or baked?

Comment: (as in where can i see it)how can I tell the difference @Programmer

Comment: it's realtime @Programmer

Comment: Ok, what's your texture size/resolution for the cube, character and floor?

Comment: wait textures or materials? and where would I see the texture resolution

Comment: @Programmer Yeah, I think they are 1024 x 1024

Comment: the thing is, it is not only the graphics which are bad quality @Programmer, but also buttons and text are bad quality, even that sign that says powered by unity is bad quality and pixelated...

Comment: BTW @programmer a material is attached to my floor not a texture

Comment: Did you make this game? How can you make that without knowing what a Texture is? I was talking about the Textures that you plug into Materials in Unity. Anyways, I will just put my answer after I go through it in a moment.

Comment: Yes I did I just am not familiar with the terminology... I am sorry...

Comment: @Programmer? you still there?

Comment: Check my answer. Put a comment under it if there is a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many things that could cause the low quality rendering of your game.

First of all, select all the lights in your scene and make sure that the *Resolution* is set to *Use Quality Settings*.

[image]

**Through Quality Settings**:

Change the Quality to Fantastic then continue to modify it from there.

**1**.Go to *Edit* -> *Project Settings* -> *Quality* then click on **Fantastic**.

[image]

Build and Test. If not good, continue reading

**2**.The Low quality image needs more anti-aliasing.

From the Quality Settings, increase the `Anti-Aliasing` to about *4x or 8x Sampling*.

**3**.Increase the `Pixel Light Count`.

**4**.You can also change the *Shadow Resolution* to *Very High Resolution*.

This is all experiment. You experiment and build each time until you find the settings that works for you. Make sure to test the frame-rate while changing these settings as they can make your game run slow.

**Through Texture Import Settings**:

If quality does not imporve, select your Textures(character, cube and floor...) one by one and change their *Format* to *Truecolor*.

[image]

Comment: sorry for hassling you again but under image settings It only shows one of the columns (the one with the arrow on top), why is this?

Comment: The texture stuff should be the last thing to try. Please try the others on top of it first. Also, it would be good to upload image of what you are talking about on imgur then post the link under this comment.

Comment: how would I get to the RAM import Setting to change the materials to true Colour?

Comment: Ok. There is no such thing as ` RAM import Setting`. The RAM you see is the name of my texture/picture which is .png, jpeg or png image if that helps. Please select your texture/image and the import settings should show up. Now change the format that I marked red in the picture in my answer to Truecolor

Comment: @ Programmer even though none of these has helped me solve my problem(which I had suspected in the first place, as it is not only graphics but also UI elements and even the powered by unity start page which is pixelated and low quality) I will still accept your answer as you must have spent a very long time and a lot of effort on it and I a sure it will be able to help other people... Thanks again for your effort!:-)

Comment: I provide answer to help as many people as possible not just for it to be accepted. You do understand that even the UI element uses textures/images too? You can make those high quality too. I do believe that you are messing up somewhere and it is really hard to know what that place is without being in from of your computer.

Comment: could it have something to do with me not having the plus/pro version of Unity @Programmer